# OpenGL text rendering - Modify single VBO or use one VBO per Text object?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I'm making a small 2D engine/game to learn OpenGL (using OpenGL 330 Core), and I am trying to abstract away most OpenGL function calls.

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to best handle text rendering. I have a font atlas working, but I'm not sure how to handle the text's vertices. Right now, I have a `Renderer` class which has a `drawText(const Text& text)` method which looks like this:

```cpp
const std::vector<Text::Vertex>& vertices = text.getVertices();
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Text::Vertex) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
```

I'm not sure that this is good because I'm redefining the contents of the VBO for every `Text` object that gets drawn and there may be multiple `Text` objects drawn per frame.

**Note:** I'm not doing batched rendering with `Text` because:

- It's a simple 2D game, so I'd rather wait for draw calls to become an actual problem before optimizing them
- `Text` can be updated in various way (i.e. becomes visible alongside a tooltip, change color when hovered, etc.) which would require me to modify the single VBO that would contain the batched vertex data

So, since my `Text` object is so volatile when it comes to transformations, should I just have a VBO per instance that would get modified when appropriate and just bind a new VBO whenever I draw text on the screen?

My understanding is that if I do this, I'll need to manually call the `glVertexAttribPointer()` method every time I bind a new VBO since binding a new VBO itself doesn't affect draw calls.

Or should I just have a single VBO and constantly update its values?

I'm not sure which is the preferred approach, and I've read that rebinding VBOs can be expensive, but I'm not sure if overwriting their data is any faster/slower. Plus, looking at SFML's source code for a real world example, they seem to be setting new vertices every time something is drawn (although their situation might be different than mine since they don't use OpenGL 3+ and don't do any batched rendering).

Answer (score 2):

Text rendering is best treated as a form of [vertex streaming](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming), since that's what it is. You should *assume* that your text is changing every frame, and just update all of it each frame. Since there's not much text, it isn't all that big of a deal to stream text data even if it didn't change.

Given that you're streaming, the best way to handle this is through mapping. You have the buffer mapped before you start looking for text to render. You write vertex data to the buffer for each glyph. And when you're finished rendering text, unmap the buffer and draw it.

Now, this assumes pure text drawing. Namely, you're not doing UI stuff, viewport scisssoring for window clipping, or the like. If you are, then things get more complex, since you're going to need to issue multiple draws from different parts of the buffers. But even in that case, what you would do is build a list of draws for your text, and then issue them after writing all of the glyph data.

Map the buffer. As you iterate through the text you need to draw, write the glyph vertex data to the mapped pointer. Once you're finished, unmap the buffer and draw your glyphs. (note: feel free to use [persistent mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Persistent_mapped_streaming) or [invalidation techniques](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Buffer_update) to improve performance. And you may need to ping-pong between regions of the buffer so that you're not syncing with the GPU).

This is about memory allocation, not the number of draw calls. You should pick a buffer size that is sufficient to draw all of the text you need to.

The main point here is fill the buffer, *then* draw from it. Don't fill and draw in the same loop, and *definitely* don't allocate buffer objects in the middle of rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is almost everything I needed! Though I was planning on eventually having something like a scroll area for my UI. Could you elaborate on the "issue multiple draws from different parts of the buffers" bit?

Do you means that I'll need to have to start drawing from an offset if, for example, the top half of my text is stenciled out of the scroll area?